# How to move the stdout pointer in python to a previous line?

Tags: python, buffer

I'm trying to print a counter while waiting for user input. So I spawn the counter in its own thread and have it run something like:

```
while waiting:
  print('Elapsed time:', time, end='\r')
```

The end argument is used to set the pointer to the beginning of the current line thus updating the displayed time instead of flooding the screen every update.

That works ok however I'd like to display something underneath this similar to commands displayed in many console based text editors and I cannot find a way to do so. I guess my question is is there a way to set where the pointer is that print will write to?

I first though sys.stdout, but when I try to do sys.stdout.seek(anoffset) (or many of the other sys.stdout calls) I get an error stating it's not seekable. Read calls say it's not readable, etc. I'm not sure what to do. If I could seek other than iterating through the whole file is there an easy way to seek to the previous line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cannot**. Standard output is simply *not meant* to do complex manipulation of the terminal. In fact even using `\r` isn't probably portable to all terminals.

What you want is a full-blown [TUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) library. The standard library provides the [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/curses.html) module to achieve that, even though it is UNIX specific.

On ANSI terminals you can use some [escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), even though you'll have a really hard time using them manually.

There are some possibilities of using `curses` on windows via cygwin and similar, however I'm not sure how do they work in practice.

It seems like [PDCurses](http://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm) works there. This library should be compatible with `curses` so you should be able to write code that works in every supported platform, with only a small number of checks. There exists python binidings already: [`python-pdcurses`](https://github.com/jmcb/python-pdcurses).

However `python-pdcurses` seems to be python2 only.

Comment: Well I don't like this answer, but I guess I shouldn't be surprised since windows has weak console support anyway. I don't think it's worth requiring another library so I'll just design around the flaws and work with what I have then, thanks.

Comment: @kryptobs2000 Well, think that most other languages don't even have curses in the standard library, so installing a specific library becomes a *necessity* when speaking of complex TUIs.

Comment: @kryptobs2000 - Windows has a console api that you can use through python via the win32api extensions.

Comment: @tdelaney At that point it would be better to use `pdcurses` since it would allow to write a cross platform program installing one extra library. Using `win32api` you are adding one dependency to obtain code that cannot be reused on other systems.

Comment: @Bakuriu - Poster doesn't say whether this should be cross-platform. If Windows only, then pdcurses is the foreign library with the risk of incompatabilities and the console is a natural choice. Depending on win32api for windows programs is normal.

Comment: @tdelaney The *question* doesn't mention windows in any part (nor in the tags). I interpret this and the comments as "windows compatibility is important" not that the code should run *only* on windows. Otherwise I'd suggest the OP to clarify this *in the question*, using the appropriate tag.

Comment: @tdelaney It should be cross platform. I'm developing on Windows but will likely deploy on linux. This rather minor thing was the only thing that would call for a curses like library so for that reason I'm just skipping it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do this within a window with `curses`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html#windows-and-pads

Comment: I want it to work on windows though, that's (unfortunately) where I'm developing it even so it's not even an option atm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in these things, but I'm pretty sure you can't back up the position in that stream.

A different approach is re-print the he entire screen every time there is an update. Then on the last line, print your banner or menu commands. Assuming a 40 line display terminal, here is some pseudo-code (I haven't tried this code):

```
#Some of the hard-coded values might be off. 
#I'm perpetually off by 1 or 2 for these kinds of thing.

listOfMessagesToPrint = [1,2,3,4,5] #list of strings. Each less than 80 characters.

print "This is the title at the top of the page"

#Print as many messages as will fit on the screen. Assume new messages are appended
for each in listOfMessagesToPrint[-38:]:
    print each

remainingLines = 38 - len(listOfMessagesToPrint)
while remainingLines > 0:
    print " "
    remainingLines -= 1

print ("This is last line on the screen")
```